# How to clicked connect button after go to today calendar widget background change?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

first self.calendar.setSelectedDate(QDate(currentYear, currentMonth, 2)) calendar widget background blue but  after  clicked connect button and goto today calendar widget background  gray self.calendar.setSelectedDate(QDate.currentDate().toPyDate())

.. How to pushbutton with goto day and selected date background blue ?

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QCalendarWidget,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

class CalendarDemo(QWidget):
    global currentYear, currentMonth

    currentMonth = datetime.now().month
    currentYear = datetime.now().year

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Calendar Demo')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 450, 300)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.calendar = QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.calendar.move(20, 20)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.move(120, 220)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonfunc)

        self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)

        self.calendar.setMinimumDate(QDate(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, 1))
        self.calendar.setMaximumDate(QDate(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, calendar.monthrange(currentYear, currentMonth)[1]))

        self.calendar.setSelectedDate(QDate(currentYear, currentMonth, 2))


    def buttonfunc(self):
        self.calendar.setSelectedDate(QDate.currentDate().toPyDate())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = CalendarDemo()
demo.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but try:

> QWidget::setFocus()
>
> Gives the keyboard input focus to this widget (or its focus proxy) if this widget or one of its parents is the active window.

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QCalendarWidget,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

class CalendarDemo(QWidget):
#???    global currentYear, currentMonth

    currentMonth = datetime.now().month
    currentYear = datetime.now().year

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Calendar Demo')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 450, 300)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.calendar = QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.calendar.move(20, 20)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.move(120, 220)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonfunc)

        self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)

        self.calendar.setMinimumDate(QDate(self.currentYear, self.currentMonth - 1, 1))
        self.calendar.setMaximumDate(QDate(self.currentYear, self.currentMonth + 1, 
                                     calendar.monthrange(self.currentYear, self.currentMonth)[1]))

        self.calendar.setSelectedDate(QDate(self.currentYear, self.currentMonth, 2))


    def buttonfunc(self):
        self.calendar.setSelectedDate(QDate.currentDate().toPyDate())
        self.calendar.setFocus()                                        # <<<=====<


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = CalendarDemo()
demo.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for effort and support... You correct understand  S. Nick . That is more like it. @7767694

Comment: @Flankes  If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour